# Azure file storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have hosted a MVC application on Azure using Cloud App service. The application has a document management module. Currently, I am storing the Documents uploaded by the user from application in Cloud App server. I have created a virtual directory which points to the Documents physical directory. The documents are stored in D drive. Whenever Azure machine reboots, my documents stored in the machine are lost.

What the better way of storing/retrieving files in an Azure hosted web application? Should I move my document management to Azure File Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I move my document management to Azure File Storage?

Yes. Or to Blob Storage or SQL, whatever suits your needs.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use normal Win32 API's for writing the file to storage then Azure Files is a great option - especially as it seems that you already have a working application. If instead you have control over how the files are written and don't mind updating to use Blob API's then you can also use Blobs.